# While refreshing Partial Copy sandbox, is Customer Community users also created with Contacts?

Tags: apex, community, email, customer-community, sandbox-refresh

I want to refresh Partial Copy sandbox with few set of objects data which includes contact records as well.

I don`t want to send any sandbox email to Community user in the process of refresh.

While refreshing Partial Copy sandbox, is Customer Community users also created with Contacts which shoots welcome / credential email to community users?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&type=5)

This will not send any emails to Community users. The records are simply replicated into your partial sandbox and the user's email will appended with `.invalid`.

Contact emails will not be changed, however, so those will need to be updated if you have any workflows or processes that may email them. Email Deliverability is set to "System Email Only" so you can make updates before turning it on if need be.

[image]